# VSTS CI - Build of ASP.NET Core 1.1 failed - Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0 not found

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, azure-pipelines, asp.net-core-1.1

I set up CI for my ASP.NET Core 1.1 project which uses Azure AD B2C (from this example - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp). So here's what I have in .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</PackageTargetFallback>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
...
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="BuildWebCompiler" Version="1.11.326" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite" Version="1.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="1.1.0-preview" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When I go to VSTS I see the following log with errors:

> > ---
> >
> > Starting: Build
> >
> > ## ******************************************************************************
> >
> > Task         : .NET Core
> >     Description  : Build, test and publish using dotnet core command-line.
> >     Version      : 1.0.2
> >     Author       : Microsoft Corporation
> >
> > ## Help         :  [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=832194)
> >
> > "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" build d:\a\1\s\MMLServices\MMLServices.csproj --configuration release
> >     Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.1012.6693
> >     Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
> >
> > C:\Users\buildguest.nuget\packages\buildwebcompiler\1.11.326\build\BuildWebCompiler.targets(15,9): error MSB4062: The "WebCompiler.CompilerBuildTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\buildguest.nuget\packages\buildwebcompiler\1.11.326\build..\tools\WebCompiler.exe. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [d:\a\1\s\MMLServices\MMLServices.csproj]
> >
> > **Build FAILED.**
> >
> > C:\Users\buildguest.nuget\packages\buildwebcompiler\1.11.326\build\BuildWebCompiler.targets(15,9): error MSB4062: The "WebCompiler.CompilerBuildTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\buildguest.nuget\packages\buildwebcompiler\1.11.326\build..\tools\WebCompiler.exe. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [d:\a\1\s\MMLServices\MMLServices.csproj]
> >         0 Warning(s)
> >         1 Error(s)
> >
> > Time Elapsed 00:00:03.66
> >     Error: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe failed with return code: 1
> >     Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : d:\a\1\s\MMLServices\MMLServices.csproj

So, how can I fix this?

**UPDATE:**

I added `debug=true`, here's the log after that (Publish task):

> > 2017-06-20T15:23:36.6048010Z [command]"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" publish d:\a\1\s\MMLServices\MMLServices.csproj --configuration release --output d:\a\1\a\MMLServices
> >     2017-06-20T15:23:36.7748032Z Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.1012.6693
> >     2017-06-20T15:23:36.7758030Z Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
> >     2017-06-20T15:23:36.7758030Z 
> >     2017-06-20T15:23:37.3732835Z
> >     C:\Users\buildguest.nuget\packages\buildwebcompiler\1.11.326\build\BuildWebCompiler.targets(15,9): error MSB4062: The "WebCompiler.CompilerBuildTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\buildguest.nuget\packages\buildwebcompiler\1.11.326\build..\tools\WebCompiler.exe. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [d:\a\1\s\MMLServices\MMLServices.csproj]
> >     2017-06-20T15:23:37.3943585Z ##[debug]rc:1
> >     2017-06-20T15:23:37.3943585Z ##[debug]success:false
> >     2017-06-20T15:23:37.3973597Z ##[error]Error: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe failed with return code: 1
> >     2017-06-20T15:23:37.3973597Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Error: C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe failed with return code: 1
> >     2017-06-20T15:23:37.4003593Z ##[debug]task result: Failed
> >     2017-06-20T15:23:37.4003593Z ##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : d:\a\1\s\MMLServices\MMLServices.csproj
> >     2017-06-20T15:23:37.4003593Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : d:\a\1\s\MMLServices\MMLServices.csproj
> >     2017-06-20T15:23:37.4034692Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : d:\a\1\s\MMLServices\MMLServices.csproj
> >     2017-06-20T15:23:37.4073330Z ##[section]Finishing: Publish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I removed that Build definition and added a new one - this time with ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework) template and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related do donet build with BuildWebCompiler package. You can use Visual Studio Build task instead:

1. Remove .NET Core Build task
2. Add Visual Studio build task (Solution: ***.sln; Visual Studio Version: Visual Studio 2017)

Update:

Regarding publish, you can refer to these steps (can’t use dotnet publish):

1. Create a web deploy package publish profile in Visual Studio and add to source control

Sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>Package</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <PublishFramework>netcoreapp1.1</PublishFramework>
    <ProjectGuid>6ecb453c-aea3-44af-8185-059fbac7b56c</ProjectGuid>
    <DesktopBuildPackageLocation>E:\yy\WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet.zip</DesktopBuildPackageLocation>
    <PackageAsSingleFile>true</PackageAsSingleFile>
    <DeployIisAppPath>Default Web Site/tt</DeployIisAppPath>
    <PublishDatabaseSettings>
      <Objects xmlns="" />
    </PublishDatabaseSettings>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

2. Remove .NET Core tasks (e.g. publish, build)
3. Specify this MSBuild Arguments for Visual Studio Build task

:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=[publish profile];DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet.zip"
```

Comment: That didn't help. Same thing.

Comment: @alvipeo Can you share the detail build log on the OneDrive? (set system.debug to true>queue build>share log files) On the other hand, can you reproduce this issue with a new project? If so, you can share this project on the OneDrive too.

Comment: I can give you access to my VSTS if you want. DM me ... is there any private communication on GitHub?

Comment: @alvipeo It's better to share the build log and a simple project directly.

Comment: just to clarify - where do you want me this 'set system.debug to true' to be set?

Comment: @alvipeo It is a variable (Open build definition>Variables)

Comment: What's your GitHub acc? I have prepared a private repo.

Comment: or MS account, so I can add you to my VSTS

Comment: @alvipeo Using Visual Studio Build task to publish instead, I updated my answer.

Comment: ok, that one _almost_ worked. It built the proj but Release failed because it couldn't find a package. So how can I specify that?

Comment: @alvipeo You need to publish the web published files (e.g. zip) to artifact. 1. Add Publish Build Artifacts to build definition (Path to publish: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)). 2. Add Azure App Service Deploy task to release definition (Package or folder: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\**\*.zip; Check Publish using Web Deploy option)

Comment: I tried that but here's the thing - Building solution succeeds, and I see this param for MSBuild: 'DesktopBuildPackageLocation="d:\a\1\a\MMLServices.zip"'. but the task 'Publish Artifact' says '[warning]Directory 'd:\a\1\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'. So what's deleting it?

Comment: @alvipeo What's the code of your publish profile? On the other hand, you can share the detail log files on the OneDrive.

Comment: Here's the whole project - https://inus.blob.core.windows.net/pub/MMLServices.zip?st=2017-06-27T05%3A44%3A00Z&se=2017-06-29T05%3A44%3A00Z&sp=rl&sv=2015-12-11&sr=b&sig=8ASdWDvaFsrVUI9C1dZ%2FgiWGsTWpMwXZ0QZvc2yG3LQ%3D . It'll expire in 2 days.

Comment: @alvipeo It works fine for me. MSBuild Arguments: /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=2mls_cd;DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\MMLServices.zip" The Build log files: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AresBGZVYryjhS0T9WbXTqRBn0AL. Can you share the build log files on the OneDrive?

Comment: Here's the log - https://inus.blob.core.windows.net/pub/logs_138.zip?st=2017-06-28T02%3A22%3A00Z&se=2017-06-30T02%3A22%3A00Z&sp=rl&sv=2015-12-11&sr=b&sig=uV8pcTbtd5Hef62ffmHtug0O8c6k8mzZ8o7UjU6zGbs%3D

Comment: @alvipeo Specify any cpu platform and release configuration for Visual Studio Build task (You can use $(BuildPlatform) and $(BuildConfiguration), then set the values in variables tab)

Comment: It is there. Nothing to change.

Comment: @alvipeo Based on the build log, you are using debug, any cpu. Change debug to release. https://1drv.ms/i/s!AresBGZVYryjhS8qbqsrHQnw3zrY  and https://1drv.ms/i/s!AresBGZVYryjhS7QApCdTKytjWaF

Comment: @alvipeo You can override configuration and platform of publish profile by using this msbuild argumments: /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="2mls_cd";DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\MMLServices.zip";LastUsedBuildConfiguration="$(BuildConfiguration)";LastUsedPlatform="$(BuildPlatform)"

Comment: I don't know guys, call me stupid. But I see this 'Directory 'd:\a\1\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'.' in the log :( But build succeeded

Comment: @alvipeo Using this [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/definitions#get-a-build-definition)to get build definition and share the result on the OneDrive. On the other hand, try it with /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="2mls_cd";DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(b‌​uild.artifactstaging‌​directory)\MMLServic‌​es.zip";LastUsedBuil‌​dConfiguration="$(Bu‌​ildConfiguration)";L‌​astUsedPlatform="$(B‌​uildPlatform)"

Comment: Here - https://inus.blob.core.windows.net/pub/build-def.json?st=2017-06-30T09%3A10%3A00Z&se=2017-07-04T09%3A10%3A00Z&sp=rl&sv=2015-12-11&sr=b&sig=MWwZFf4IEYQrZLER6bqOmpTADCzS3PE4MDYSA%2FmLg28%3D . Changed some personal data, don't want to expose my email and domain names.

Comment: @alvipeo Based on the build definition JSON file, you don't specify [Platform and configuration for Visual Studio Build task](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21ACpuqysdCfDfOtg&cid=A3BC62556604ACB7&id=A3BC62556604ACB7%21687&parId=A3BC62556604ACB7%21671&o=OneUp), close internet explorer and open it again, then check platform and configuration again.

Comment: Please give me a day, too busy.

Comment: ok, I removed that build definition and selected VS2017 Core and it all works now!